# Did Kamsa have any children?

Tags: puranas

Did Kamsa have any children. What I know is that Jarasandha’s daughters were married to him. But I have not come across any reference to his children. Can anyone throw some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all very good question hard to find the answer and also there is no mention of successors of Kamsa in any document or website I referred.
And also there is mentioned that he has no successor in below paragraph but not confirmed too.

> This below paragraph is from [vaniquotes.org](https://vaniquotes.org/wiki/Kamsa_had_two_queens,_Asti_and_Prapti,_and_both_happened_to_be_the_daughters_of_King_Jarasandha)
>
> *As above paragraph describing Vedic civilization for wives of Kamsa the paragraph mentioned he has no Successor.*
>
> > Upon Kaṁsa's death, his two wives became widows. According to Vedic civilization, a woman is never independent. She has three stages of life: in childhood a woman should live under the protection of her father, a youthful woman should live under the protection of her young husband, and in the event of the death of her husband she should live under the protection of her grown-up sons, or if she has no grown-up sons she must go back to her father and live as a widow under his protection. **It appears that Kaṁsa had no grown-up sons.** Therefore, after his wives became widows they returned to the shelter of their father. Kaṁsa had two queens, Asti and Prāpti, and both happened to be the daughters of King Jarāsandha, the lord of the Bihar Province (known in those days as Magadha). After reaching home, the two queens explained their awkward position following Kaṁsa's death. The King of Magadha, Jarāsandha, was mortified on hearing of the pitiable condition of his daughters. When informed of the death of Kaṁsa, Jarāsandha decided on the spot that he would rid the world of all the members of the Yadu dynasty. He decided that since Kṛṣṇa had killed Kaṁsa, the whole dynasty of the Yadus should be killed.